# Google OAuth in android not working with react native expo

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-oauth

I am using React native to make app for both android and ios. The google auth goes to web browser, where the account is chosen. In ios, it redirects back to the app but in android, it does not redirect to the app but goes to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) in that browser.
I am using expo to run the app during development. How can this issue be fixed?

I used different ways of making the redirect uri but none of them work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.